# Is there a faster way to solve this linear programming problem?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-algebra

I need to get a rational solution of the linear constraints
`p={1-49 Subscript[a15, 56]-Subscript[a4, 1]==0,-1+140 Subscript[a15, 56]-Subscript[a4, 2]==0,-100 Subscript[a15, 56]+2 Subscript[a4, 1]-Subscript[a4, 4]==0,-13 Subscript[a30, 16]-Subscript[a4, 7]+2 Subscript[a4, 16]-Subscript[a4, 29]==0,-49 Subscript[a15, 56]+4 Subscript[a21, 3]-Subscript[a30, 37]-Subscript[a4, 1]+2 Subscript[a4, 3]-Subscript[a4, 37]==0,-Subscript[a27, 37]+6 Subscript[a30, 16]-4 Subscript[a30, 37]-Subscript[a4, 11]+2 Subscript[a4, 22]-Subscript[a4, 37]==0,-Subscript[a27, 37]-13 Subscript[a30, 37]-Subscript[a4, 22]+2 Subscript[a4, 37]==0,-Subscript[a1, 3]+2 Subscript[a1, 5]+4 Subscript[a12, 55]+200 Subscript[a15, 56]-4 Subscript[a21, 3]-2 Subscript[a4, 1]-2 Subscript[a4, 2]+2 Subscript[a4, 3]+2 Subscript[a4, 4]-Subscript[a4, 8]-Subscript[a4, 46]==0,2 Subscript[a27, 37]-Subscript[a30, 16]+12 Subscript[a30, 37]-Subscript[a4, 16]+2 Subscript[a4, 29]-Subscript[a4, 46]==0,-Subscript[a21, 3]+6 Subscript[a30, 37]-Subscript[a4, 3]-Subscript[a4, 29]+2 Subscript[a4, 46]==0,-Subscript[a12, 55]+2 Subscript[a4, 2]-Subscript[a4, 7]-Subscript[a4, 59]==0,-Subscript[a12, 55]-8 Subscript[a27, 37]+2 Subscript[a4, 22]-2 Subscript[a4, 29]-2 Subscript[a4, 37]+2 Subscript[a4, 46]+4 Subscript[a41, 5]==0,-Subscript[a1, 3]+98 Subscript[a15, 56]-4 Subscript[a21, 3]+2 Subscript[a4, 1]-Subscript[a4, 3]-Subscript[a4, 46]-Subscript[a42, 3]==0,2 Subscript[a12, 55]-100 Subscript[a15, 56]+4 Subscript[a21, 3]-4 Subscript[a27, 37]-Subscript[a4, 1]+2 Subscript[a4, 2]-2 Subscript[a4, 3]-Subscript[a4, 4]-2 Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 8]-Subscript[a4, 37]+2 Subscript[a4, 46]-2 Subscript[a46, 5]==0,2 Subscript[a1, 3]-Subscript[a1, 5]-280 Subscript[a15, 56]+8 Subscript[a21, 3]-2 Subscript[a4, 1]+2 Subscript[a4, 2]-Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 46]-Subscript[a46, 5]==0,-4 Subscript[a12, 55]+140 Subscript[a15, 56]-8 Subscript[a21, 3]+2 Subscript[a4, 1]-Subscript[a4, 2]-2 Subscript[a4, 3]+2 Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 37]-2 Subscript[a4, 46]+2 Subscript[a42, 3]+4 Subscript[a46, 5]==0,-Subscript[a4, 7]+2 Subscript[a4, 8]+2 Subscript[a4, 11]-2 Subscript[a4, 12]-Subscript[a4, 16]-2 Subscript[a4, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 27]-Subscript[a4, 59]+4 Subscript[a47, 24]==0,-Subscript[a1, 5]-6 Subscript[a12, 55]+2 Subscript[a4, 1]-2 Subscript[a4, 2]-2 Subscript[a4, 4]+2 Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 7]-Subscript[a4, 12]-Subscript[a51, 20]==0,-2 Subscript[a12, 55]-Subscript[a21, 3]+8 Subscript[a27, 37]-Subscript[a4, 3]+2 Subscript[a4, 5]-Subscript[a4, 8]-Subscript[a4, 19]-Subscript[a4, 29]+2 Subscript[a4, 30]+2 Subscript[a4, 37]-Subscript[a4, 46]-Subscript[a42, 3]+4 Subscript[a46, 5]+2 Subscript[a51, 20]==0,-Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 8]-Subscript[a4, 12]-Subscript[a4, 30]-Subscript[a46, 5]+4 Subscript[a51, 20]==0,-Subscript[a4, 4]+2 Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 7]-2 Subscript[a4, 8]-Subscript[a4, 11]-2 Subscript[a4, 12]+2 Subscript[a4, 17]-Subscript[a4, 24]-2 Subscript[a4, 59]+2 Subscript[a41, 5]-4 Subscript[a47, 24]-2 Subscript[a51, 20]-5 Subscript[a51, 24]==0,-13 Subscript[a30, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 7]-Subscript[a4, 8]-2 Subscript[a4, 11]-2 Subscript[a4, 16]+2 Subscript[a4, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 22]-Subscript[a4, 27]-Subscript[a4, 30]-Subscript[a51, 20]-2 Subscript[a51, 24]==0,12 Subscript[a30, 16]-Subscript[a4, 4]+2 Subscript[a4, 11]-Subscript[a4, 22]-Subscript[a51, 24]==0,2 Subscript[a12, 55]-Subscript[a4, 1]+2 Subscript[a4, 4]-Subscript[a4, 11]+2 Subscript[a4, 59]-Subscript[a51, 24]==0,-Subscript[a12, 55]-4 Subscript[a30, 16]-Subscript[a4, 2]+2 Subscript[a4, 7]-Subscript[a4, 16]-Subscript[a4, 59]+2 Subscript[a51, 24]==0,2 Subscript[a12, 55]-4 Subscript[a30, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 2]-Subscript[a4, 3]-2 Subscript[a4, 4]-2 Subscript[a4, 7]+2 Subscript[a4, 8]+2 Subscript[a4, 11]-Subscript[a4, 17]-2 Subscript[a4, 59]-2 Subscript[a51, 20]+2 Subscript[a51, 24]==0,6 Subscript[a30, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 11]-Subscript[a4, 12]-2 Subscript[a4, 16]-2 Subscript[a4, 22]+2 Subscript[a4, 27]+2 Subscript[a4, 29]-Subscript[a41, 5]+2 Subscript[a51, 20]+2 Subscript[a51, 24]==0,-Subscript[a4, 11]+2 Subscript[a4, 12]+2 Subscript[a4, 16]-2 Subscript[a4, 17]-Subscript[a4, 22]+2 Subscript[a4, 24]-2 Subscript[a4, 27]+2 Subscript[a4, 30]+4 Subscript[a41, 5]-Subscript[a47, 24]+4 Subscript[a51, 20]+3 Subscript[a51, 24]-2 Subscript[a9, 17]==0,4 Subscript[a27, 37]-Subscript[a30, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 16]-Subscript[a4, 17]-2 Subscript[a4, 22]-Subscript[a4, 27]-2 Subscript[a4, 29]+2 Subscript[a4, 30]+2 Subscript[a4, 37]-4 Subscript[a41, 5]-Subscript[a51, 20]-Subscript[a9, 17]==0,-4 Subscript[a28, 19]-Subscript[a4, 16]+2 Subscript[a4, 17]-Subscript[a4, 19]+2 Subscript[a4, 22]-Subscript[a4, 29]-2 Subscript[a4, 30]+2 Subscript[a41, 5]-2 Subscript[a51, 20]-2 Subscript[a51, 24]-4 Subscript[a9, 25]==0,Subscript[a4, 19]+2 Subscript[a4, 24]-Subscript[a4, 27]+2 Subscript[a41, 5]-Subscript[a51, 20]+2 Subscript[a51, 24]+4 Subscript[a9, 17]-2 Subscript[a9, 25]==0,4 Subscript[a28, 19]-2 Subscript[a4, 19]+2 Subscript[a4, 24]+2 Subscript[a4, 30]-Subscript[a4, 59]-Subscript[a51, 20]-2 Subscript[a51, 24]+4 Subscript[a9, 17]-Subscript[a9, 25]==0,-8 Subscript[a28, 19]-2 Subscript[a4, 19]-2 Subscript[a4, 24]+2 Subscript[a4, 27]-Subscript[a47, 24]-2 Subscript[a51, 20]+4 Subscript[a9, 25]==0,2 Subscript[a28, 19]-Subscript[a4, 12]+2 Subscript[a4, 17]-2 Subscript[a4, 24]-2 Subscript[a4, 27]+4 Subscript[a47, 24]+3 Subscript[a51, 20]+4 Subscript[a51, 24]-4 Subscript[a9, 17]+4 Subscript[a9, 25]==0,4 Subscript[a12, 55]+2 Subscript[a21, 3]+4 Subscript[a27, 37]+2 Subscript[a4, 3]-Subscript[a4, 5]+2 Subscript[a4, 29]-Subscript[a4, 30]-2 Subscript[a4, 37]-2 Subscript[a4, 46]-Subscript[a41, 5]-4 Subscript[a46, 5]-4 Subscript[a9, 35]==0,-Subscript[a28, 19]-Subscript[a4, 8]+2 Subscript[a4, 12]-Subscript[a4, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 19]+2 Subscript[a4, 24]-Subscript[a4, 27]+2 Subscript[a4, 59]-5 Subscript[a41, 5]+4 Subscript[a51, 20]-Subscript[a9, 17]-2 Subscript[a9, 35]==0,12 Subscript[a30, 17]+2 Subscript[a4, 4]-Subscript[a4, 5]-2 Subscript[a4, 7]-2 Subscript[a4, 11]+2 Subscript[a4, 12]+2 Subscript[a4, 16]+2 Subscript[a4, 59]-Subscript[a51, 20]-2 Subscript[a51, 24]-Subscript[a9, 35]==0,7 Subscript[a28, 19]-Subscript[a4, 17]+Subscript[a4, 19]-2 Subscript[a4, 24]+2 Subscript[a4, 27]-Subscript[a4, 30]-Subscript[a41, 5]-2 Subscript[a47, 24]-3 Subscript[a51, 20]-Subscript[a9, 25]-Subscript[a9, 35]==0,-4 Subscript[a27, 37]+2 Subscript[a4, 19]-Subscript[a4, 22]-Subscript[a4, 24]+2 Subscript[a4, 29]-2 Subscript[a4, 30]-Subscript[a4, 37]-2 Subscript[a41, 5]-2 Subscript[a51, 20]-2 Subscript[a51, 24]+4 Subscript[a9, 35]==0,Subscript[a12, 55]-Subscript[a4, 2]+2 Subscript[a4, 3]+2 Subscript[a4, 4]-2 Subscript[a4, 5]-Subscript[a4, 7]-2 Subscript[a4, 8]+2 Subscript[a4, 12]+2 Subscript[a4, 59]+2 Subscript[a51, 24]+4 Subscript[a9, 35]==0,Subscript[a1, 3]>=0,Subscript[a1, 5]>=0,Subscript[a12, 55]>=0,Subscript[a15, 56]>=0,Subscript[a21, 3]>=0,Subscript[a27, 37]>=0,Subscript[a28, 19]>=0,Subscript[a30, 16]>=0,Subscript[a30, 17]>=0,Subscript[a30, 37]>=0,Subscript[a4, 1]>=0,Subscript[a4, 2]>=0,Subscript[a4, 3]>=0,Subscript[a4, 4]>=0,Subscript[a4, 5]>=0,Subscript[a4, 7]>=0,Subscript[a4, 8]>=0,Subscript[a4, 11]>=0,Subscript[a4, 12]>=0,Subscript[a4, 16]>=0,Subscript[a4, 17]>=0,Subscript[a4, 19]>=0,Subscript[a4, 22]>=0,Subscript[a4, 24]>=0,Subscript[a4, 27]>=0,Subscript[a4, 29]>=0,Subscript[a4, 30]>=0,Subscript[a4, 37]>=0,Subscript[a4, 46]>=0,Subscript[a4, 59]>=0,Subscript[a41, 5]>=0,Subscript[a42, 3]>=0,Subscript[a46, 5]>=0,Subscript[a47, 24]>=0,Subscript[a51, 20]>=0,Subscript[a51, 24]>=0,Subscript[a9, 17]>=0,Subscript[a9, 25]>=0,Subscript[a9, 35]>=0}`

the variables are

`vars={Subscript[a1, 3],Subscript[a1, 5],Subscript[a12, 55],Subscript[a15, 56],Subscript[a21, 3],Subscript[a27, 37],Subscript[a28, 19],Subscript[a30, 16],Subscript[a30, 17],Subscript[a30, 37],Subscript[a4, 1],Subscript[a4, 2],Subscript[a4, 3],Subscript[a4, 4],Subscript[a4, 5],Subscript[a4, 7],Subscript[a4, 8],Subscript[a4, 11],Subscript[a4, 12],Subscript[a4, 16],Subscript[a4, 17],Subscript[a4, 19],Subscript[a4, 22],Subscript[a4, 24],Subscript[a4, 27],Subscript[a4, 29],Subscript[a4, 30],Subscript[a4, 37],Subscript[a4, 46],Subscript[a4, 59],Subscript[a41, 5],Subscript[a42, 3],Subscript[a46, 5],Subscript[a47, 24],Subscript[a51, 20],Subscript[a51, 24],Subscript[a9, 17],Subscript[a9, 25],Subscript[a9, 35]}`

now I need to get a rational solution of `p`.
I tried `FindInstance` `LinearOptimization` and `Minimize` and different methods are different in speed.
For example, use `Minimize[Total[vars],p,vars]//AbsoluteTiming`, it takes 0.401411 seconds and output an exact rational solution. Use `FindInstance[p,vars]`, it takes 0.545074 seconds and output an exact rational solution, slower than the first method. Use `LinearOptimization[Total[vars],p,vars,Method->"Simplex"]`, it takes 2.08624 seconds and output an exact rational solution, much slower than the first method. Use `LinearOptimization[Total[vars],p,vars,Method->"CLP"]`, it takes only 0.0067805 seconds, much faster than all the methods, but the result is numerical.
Is there any method to get an rational solution while as faster as possible? Thanks.

Comment: `(nmin = NMinimize[{Total[vars], p}, vars, WorkingPrecision -> 100, 
     AccuracyGoal -> 20, PrecisionGoal -> 20] // 
    Rationalize[#, 0] &) // AbsoluteTiming` yields the same result as Minimize and is abourt 5 times faster.

Answer (score 12):

Your problem is not a linear programming problem, but rather a linear system of equations. You have 40 equations for 39 variables and so the problem is over-determined, but luckily it is still solvable.

First, extract the coefficients of the problem into matrix/vector representation:

```
M = D[p[[;; 40, 1]], {vars}];
b = p[[;; 40, 1]] - M . vars;
```

Now $M$ is a $40\times39$ matrix and $b$ is a 40-vector; your problem can now be written as $M\cdot x+b=0$. We solve it with [`LinearSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LinearSolve.html) in a fraction of a millisecond:

```
x = LinearSolve[M, -b]; // RepeatedTiming // First
(*    0.000353668    *)

x
(*    {1783932837904341077/2780412442842475762,
       594136606591323051/1390206221421237881,
       147462186435643008/1390206221421237881,
       ...,
       294293138346748441/5560824885684951524}    *)
```

All coefficients in $x$ are nonnegative, so your constraints are satisfied:

```
p /. Thread[vars -> x]
(*    {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
       True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True,
       ...
       True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}    *)
```